# Where is my MVC 5 code-first database created? (not using AttachDbFilename)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string, sql-server-express, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following connection string in my MVC 5 weApp:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;User Instance=True;Initial Catalog=MatWebDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using Entity Framework code-first and Identity 2 for forms authentication.

Evreything seems to work fine: i register a new user and it logs in properly.
The problem is that i cannot find the database that was created; in my SQL Server Management Studio there is no "MatWebDB" database created.

What i want to do is to use the same database generated automatically by the Identity 2 authentication, for my own POCO entity objects. And know where is it created.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you connect to .\SQLEXPRESS in SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to combine them is to have your application context inherit from the identity context and set the connection string there:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // Use an initializer that will create the database, or create it in SSMS first
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }

    // Your identity and application tables will be created in the database this connect string points to
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", false)
    {    }

    // define your POCOs here
    public virtual DbSet<Foo1> Foo1s { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Foo2> Foo2s { get; set; }
    .. etc

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
In Solution Explorer, there is a default folder named "App_Data" firstly, just click to select this folder.

[image: As you seen in this image.]

**Step 2:**
 Now click the above menu bar icon i.e "show all" as shown in the below image.

[image: clicking the menu will show your db inside App_Data Folder.]

You will find your db there, just double click on db file,for editing or add new tables.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply. In your    `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
```

Using code first and Sqlserver:

If you have a local database you use a connection string like so:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplicationMVC-xxxx.mdf;
    Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplicationMVC-xxxxx;Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To see the database in visual studio:

[image]

If you have a database hosted on an online server:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    connectionString="Data Source=SQLxxxxx;integrated security=false;
    Initial Catalog=DB_9D914B_kermit;User Id=DBxxxxx;Password=xxxx;
    Trusted_Connection=false;TrustServerCertificate=false;Encrypt=False;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

To see the database in SQL server management studio:

[image]

The security attributes of the connection strings can be varied to suit your needs.